# How is *linear transfromation* defined?

Tags: linear-transformations, definition, mathematical-physics

The term *linear mapping* is clear to me.  It means that given a vector space $\left\{\mathfrak{u},\mathfrak{v},\dots\right\}$ over a field, $\left\{a,b,\dots\right\},$ a mapping $L$ is linear if and only if $L\left(a\mathfrak{u}+b\mathfrak{v}\right)=aL\left(\mathfrak{u}\right)+bL\left(\mathfrak{v}\right).$  If we call that mapping a transformation, saying that it is a linear transformation is uncontroversial.

In physics it is common to call a combination rotation and a translation a *linear transformation.*   As we see, such a transformation is not a linear mapping

\begin{align*}
T\left(\mathfrak{x}\right)= & \mathfrak{y}_{o}+\mathfrak{R}\mathfrak{x}=\mathfrak{y}\\
T\left(a\mathfrak{x}_{1}+b\mathfrak{x}_{2}\right)= & \mathfrak{y}_{o}+a\mathfrak{R}\mathfrak{x}_{1}+b\mathfrak{R}\mathfrak{x}_{2}\\
aT\left(\mathfrak{x}_{1}\right)+bT\left(\mathfrak{x}_{2}\right)= & \left(a+b\right)\mathfrak{y}_{o}+a\mathfrak{R}\mathfrak{x}_{1}+b\mathfrak{R}\mathfrak{x}_{2}
\end{align*}

The rotational part alone does, however, qualify as a linear mapping

$$\mathfrak{R}\left(a\mathfrak{x}_{1}+b\mathfrak{x}_{2}\right)=a\mathfrak{R}\mathfrak{x}_{1}+b\mathfrak{R}\mathfrak{x}_{2}.$$

Some mathematicians, at least informally, say that a linear transformation of $\mathbb{R}^n$ leaves the origin fixed.  So, my question is this: **is there a generally agreed upon definition of *linear transformation*? If so, what is it?**

Comment: Yes, the first thing.

Comment: Mathematicians generally call the physicists' concept an _affine transformation_ (if it's of the form $T(v) = Av + b$ for a suitable-sized matrix $A$), or a _proper rigid_ (_Euclidean_) _motion_ if $A$ is a rotation matrix.

Comment: Linear always means fixing the origin. The more general notion of a composition of a linear transformation and a translation is sometimes called an affine transformation.

Comment: I think even physicists usually recognize the latter as "affine".

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang I should have asked the question your comment addresses.  That is: what should we call a transformation of the form $T(v) = Av + b$?  I haven't seen this addressed very often, but there is a disconnect between what a physicist (Einstein included) calls a linear transformation, and what a mathematician means by the same term.

Comment: @StevenThomasHatton Andrew mentioned in the previous comment $T(v):=Av+b$ is called an affine transformation (the special case $b=0$ is called linear). If you're really working with vector spaces over fields (eg the various tangent spaces of a manifold), I don't think I've ever heard anyone (even physicists) incorrectly interchange 'linear' and 'affine', and if you ever see that they do, hopefully context will tell you which meaning is intended, and how to correctly rephrase it.

Comment: Now, I'm not sure about the history of the usage of the term, so I can't comment about Einstein's usage (100 years ago) of 'linear' in place of 'affine'.